PHP - how to set encoding to windows-1250 (or central european) in PDO_SQLSRV?
Maybe I missed sth, but I'm a little shocked how sth so basic turn out to be so difficult.
I use pdo_sqlsrv to get data from server and I get it in UTF-8 (library default). I need it in windows-1250.
Tried all this options:
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_DEFAULT);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY);

SQLSRV_ENCODING_WINDOWS1250 - there is really no option like this?
I tried Client_CSet=UTF-8;Server_CSet=Windows-1251 in connection string but it returns error (I guess its option from other PDO library).
Iconv worked on php side, but I down want to use it everywhere I output data. How can I get windows 1250?

Based on the online documentation, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY  is not supported, so you may use one of the  PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8 and PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM constants. I usually use iconv() for this purpose (... to convert UTF-8 data to/from windows-1251).

Yes. That is what I figured out too. Thing is that I would prefer not to change all the big code (adding iconv everythere) instead of proper solution. What you are saying is there is really no proper solution, and one MUST use iconv?

It was a long time ago, but if I remember correctly, I had to choose between: 1) A combination between PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8 and iconv() or 2) A PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM and the appropriate server environment (Windows server with the appropriate region settings as host operating system).

Also, note that CharacterSet connection option is not supported in the PDO_SQLSRV driver.

Hmmm. I migrate to new php, and there is lot of stuff to change. I see adding iconv to the code will be another thing to do. Well... thanx for all the info anyway.
